# Only 4 URLs indexed in Google Search Console Sitemaps

Tags: google-search-console

I am new to the whole SEO game. I have an eCommerce site running WordPress/WooCommerce. I also have the Yoast SEO plugin, and have done the basics, such as `alt` text on images, using friendly URLs, having `h1` tags when I need, etc.

Yet on Google Search Console, I see the following:

[image: indexed urls]

I'm no expert, but I think that is bad right? I should have more than 4 URLs indexed!

My blog alone has 4 posts, couple that with the homepage, the about page, the shop page and I have 6 product pages, that becomes 13 pages.

Why is this happening? I know for a fact you can navigate to all these pages from the homepage.

Comment: Seems you just changed from http to https, that being the case - check you are looking at https in webmaster tools and that the sitemap has https urls. Then check in search results with a site:search, do you have https urls indexed or are they still http. If so, it will take a little time to recrawl and shift over.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reporting bug that's happened to many people, where the number of indexed URLs shown in the sitemaps feature in Google Search Console isn't representative of the actual number of indexed pages. There's no actual problem and the pages are indexed, as can be confirmed by **checking the [Index Status](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/index-status) feature**.

[image]

Comment: On that feature, I'm getting `Total Indexed` as `0`! :/

Comment: @Ciwan How recently did you add your site to GSC? The Index Status is updated a lot less frequently and it's possible it hasn't updated at all yet?

Comment: About 5 days ago. Is that too soon?

Comment: @Ciwan Probably, just checked mine and it seems to update every 7 days.

Comment: @Ciwan Oh! This is way too soon!! It takes at least 30 days for Google to collect enough information for Google to make clear metrics. As well, too few pages will not allow the site to compete. Remember you have to compete with all of the other sites that exist. If your site is weak as compared to the market, then you will have trouble making headway. Create a strong site and do not worry about what Google thinks for quite a while. When you feel that you **do** compete, then begin getting into the metrics weeds. Keep your head down and do some work before you look up again. Cheers!!